# Running a python file in a directory

Tags: python, linux, debian

This may be a basic question but is there any difference in these two:

First:

```
cd /dir/
python run.py
```

Second:

```
python /dir/run.py
```

It seems previously executing them in these different ways seemed to cause different results, but it may be down to another factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__file__` variable is set differently so it will have impact on calling resources inside your script (different relative paths).

Comment: Also, current working directory as returned by `os.getcwd()` gets changed.